# Is there a tool that lets me query a websites content?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, website

I am currently doing extensive research on various websites which are all public available.

I was wondering whether there is an extension for Chrome (or Firefox or even an external tool) that allows me to query the websites content like if I would be using regular expressions.

I think you can use `google.com` but this is not very convenient as it does not give a lot of options regarding queries and I have to switch to `google.com` back again all the time.

Comment: If you are open to scripting solutions, you might check out http://scrapy.org/

Comment: That looks awesome, but for what I"m doing now, this is definitve an overkill. But this sure might come in handy in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

gnuwin32 has `wget` to get pages and `grep` to query them, and you can use `powergrep` or a free alternative -- maybe agent ransack can search within files.
You just have to download the webpages as files.

Answer (score 0):

First, check out Google Custom Search.  It does have a free search option, but if this is for funded research, it may be worth paying for the service so that you can query Google with much greater frequency.  I didn't check pricing, but I don't believe it is to expensive.  The free service only offers 200 free searches per day.

[Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)

Next, study up on the various Google search options.  [Google Guide](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html) has an excellent list of advanced search operators, which you can use with your custom search.

There are also a few command-line based tools that people have created that use the Google Custom Search tool.  Most of these can be found by Googling for such a tool that is specific to your operating system.  These tools should help you obtain the raw information that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not a Chrome extension, you can take a look at [YQL (Yahoo Query Language)](http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/) which can let you do a [select * from Internet](http://icant.co.uk/whyyql/#header9)